# structures in c : declaring the new variable in the structure itself

Tags: c, struct, declaration, typedef, incomplete-type

Can you explain how we can declare a variable we are currently creatin inside the structure itself please.

```
typedef struct var var;
struct var {
       int a ;
       var b; };
```

Comment: What do you think the size of such a structure would be?

Comment: You can't. `error: field 'b' has incomplete type`. You can use a pointer. `var *b;`.

Comment: You can create a *pointer* member to the same type, but obviously (?) not another instance of the same struct - that would be a recursive definition.

Comment: No, nobody can explain this for the same reason as nobody can explain how to store a box inside itself.

Comment: @dbush just tried and i think b needs to be a pointer for the size to exist correct ?

Answer (score 2):

When you are declaring the variable `b` within the structure

```
typedef struct var var;
struct var {
       int a ;
       var b; };
```

the type `struct var` is yet an incomplete type. Its size is unknown. So the compiler does not know how much memory to allocate for the data member `b` and how align data members within the structure. So you may not declare an object such a way.

From the C Standard ([6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1))

> [8](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p8) The presence of a struct-declaration-list in a
> struct-or-union-specifier declares a new type, within a translation
> unit. The struct-declaration-list is a sequence of declarations for
> the members of the structure or union. If the struct-declaration-list
> contains no named members, no anonymous structures, and no anonymous
> unions, the behavior is undefined. **The type is incomplete until
> immediately after the } that terminates the list, and complete
> thereafter**

But you may use a pointer to an object of the type `struct var` because pointers are always complete types. For example

```
typedef struct var var;
struct var {
       int a ;
       var *b; };
```

Comment: yes thank you but can you explain this structure a bit more

Comment: @KenZa What is unclear?

Comment: @Vlad_from_Moscow what does it exactly do ? if i declare a variable x of type var i will need to enter an integer and a pointer of type var too which means this pointer will link to another var variable ?

Comment: sorry i'm still not used to the website

Answer (score 0):

In [§6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers ¶3](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p3), the C11 standard says:

> A structure or union shall not contain a member with incomplete or function type (hence, a structure shall not contain an instance of itself, but may contain a pointer to an instance of itself) …

You are attempting to include a member of the same type as the structure you are defining, which is still an incomplete type.  That is a 'constraint', which means that a compiler is required to diagnose the problem.

Additionally, the structure you propose would require an infinite amount of storage space, since the structure contains an `int` and a copy of itself, which contains an `int` and another copy of itself, which …

Comment: what would the struture mean if b was a pointer

Comment: If `b` is a pointer (`var *b;`), then you'd have a structure that contains an `int` and a pointer to another structure of the same type — something that could be used as part of a singly-linked list, for example.  You can use pointers to incomplete types in many places, and they provide a mechanism for creating opaque types, where the details of the contents of the type are hidden from the clients.  In standard C, the `FILE` type is opaque (though many implementations do reveal what it contains so that macros can be written using those internals).

Comment: thanks for the answer